# android intent.ACTION_SEND WhatsApp, Edit message before sending

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, start-activity, viber

*Hi Everyone,
My question is simple but still did not find any answer for it,
when i use the Android Intent.ACTION_SEND in my App with a pre-filled message, i get the chooser, and when select WhatsApp for example (or Viber same behaviour), i cannot modify the text before sharing it with a contact.

So my question is: How can i EDIT the pre-filled message before sending it to the chosen contact.

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share Action"));
```

Thanks a lot!
Have a nice day *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can't.

After you selected the App (i.e WhatsApp) from the Chooser, Your app have no control. It is now up to the chosen app to decide how to handle the message.

If you want to modify it, you should do it before firing your shareIntent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, too bad,i bet also that there is no way to get to know the user choice, or is it possible?
I mean  get the chosen application package name like(if the user choose Whats-App or Viber or gmail from his list)

Comment: If you use the system chooser, you can't know. However, if you implemented your own chooser, you can achieve your goal here, the downside is, you need to add extra permissions to your app in order to be able to retrieve the list of apps (packages) installed in the device.